# a bit is set unexpectedly in bitmasking

Tags: java, set, bit-manipulation, bit, bitmask

I am trying to implement set which can only store values upto 60 through bitmasking (constant space and time).
But whenever i try to set a particular bit another bit also sets.

Here, `x.print()` is giving  the output of `[ 5, 37, ]` while i was only **adding 5** to it .Can anybody explain why this is happening what i am doing wrong here. Your answer is highly appreciated.

```
class Set60 {
  long num;

  Set60() {
    num = 0;
  }

  public long getNum() {
    return num;
  }

  private boolean check(int x) {
    return x <= 60;
  }

  public void add(int x) {
    if (check(x)) {
      int mask = (1 << (x - 1));
      num = num | mask;
    }
  }

  public void remove(int x) {
    if (check(x)) {
      int mask = ~(1 << (x - 1));
      num = num & mask;
    }
  }

  public void print() {
    System.out.print("[ ");
    for (int bits = 0; bits <= 60; bits++) {
      if ((num & (1 << bits)) >= 1)
        System.out.printf("%d, ", bits + 1);
    }
    System.out.println(" ]");
  }
}

public class MyClass {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set60 x = new Set60();
    x.add(5);
    x.print();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hint: `1 << bits` doesn't do what you expect it to when `bits` is greater than 31. Try `1L << bits` instead. (Likewise everywhere else where you're shifting.)

Comment: Indeed you are right. Thank you  bro.

Comment: Change `for (int bits = 0; bits <= 60; bits++)` to `for (long bits = 0; bits <= 60; bits++)`